# Is there a way to solve it by using exclusion-inclusion method

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many functions $f:\{1,2,3 \cdots n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3 \cdots n\}$ have no fixed points? Is there a way to solve it by using exclusion-inclusion method?

Comment: What do *you* get when you try to apply inclusion/exclusion formula? For example, set $A_i $ to be the set of all functions that fix $i $...

Comment: first I try to use inclusion/exclusion method to solve the problem just like Derangement problem does

Comment: Yep, can you please update the question with what you have calculated so far and where you are stuck. I guess the sum you get is big and you don't see the way to reduce it - at least we can check if you got that sum right.

Comment: $$ n^n-{n \choose 1}(n-1)^{n-1}+{n \choose 2}(n-2)^{n-2}-\cdots \pm {n \choose n} $$

Comment: Why $(n-1)^{n-1} $, for instance? Isn't it $n^{n-1} $? (You don't care where the other elements go.)

Answer (score 2):

Huh... Exclusion-inclusion principle can be used, but it is a very convoluted way to get to the solution that is actually very simple...

So... applying exclusion-inclusion principle... from all functions take away those that fix 1, 2,... n, then add those that fix pairs etc. - you end up with:

$$n^n-\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}n^{n-k} $$

which is:

$$n^n+\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}n^{n-k} $$

i.e.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}n^{n-k} = (n-1)^n$$

And, of course, this is correct by a simple combinatorial argument. (for $f (k) $ you have $n-1$ choices - any number but $k $).

Comment: Great solution +1